# std::unexpected constructor constraint

Tags: c++, c++23, std-expected

I am reading the cpp 23 standard and I stumbled upon `std::unexpected`.

Section [expected.un.cons](https://eel.is/c++draft/expected.un.cons) defines

```
template<class Err = E>
constexpr explicit unexpected(Err&& e);
```

with the following costraint (among others)

```
is_same_v<remove_cvref_t<Err>, unexpected> is false;
```

When would this expression be true given that unexpected is a class template?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`unexpected` is the *injected-class-name* in the scope of the class template. It refers to the current specialization of the template. It does not refer to the template itself as the same name would outside the class scope.

For example if you write

```
template<typename T>
struct X {
    static X x;
};
```

then `X<T>::x` is of type `X<T>`. You don't have to repeat the template argument list in the declaration of `x`. If none is given, then it resolves to the injected-class-name which refers to the current specialization of the template with the same template argument list.

The constraint is there so that the constructor can't be chosen over the copy constructor in overload resolution, which may otherwise happen for non-`const` lvalue arguments.

Comment: Do you mean the move constructor (non const lvalues)? 

I am trying with this code but I cannot see an effect of the constraint https://godbolt.org/z/s3MnE3463

Comment: @NikBomb No I mean the copy constructor without `std::move`. See https://godbolt.org/z/q691Y6aro.

Comment: I see, thank you! Any particular reason as to why the copy constructor should be preferred in the case of wrapper/monadic types? I see `std::optional` does something similar.

Comment: @NikBomb The forwarding constructor tries to initialize the contained object (of type `E`) with the argument. You usually can't initialize a `E` from a `unexpected<E>`. It would simply fail to compile or potentially have the wrong semantics if `E` has a constructor from `unexpected<E>`. The copy constructor is supposed to copy the whole `unexpected<E>` without details of `E` affecting it.